# CloudFormation: AWS::Lambda::Function code as a file from bucket of another region

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

For now it is possible to specify a zip-file from S3 bucket as a source code of Lambda function for CloudFormation configuration:

```
...
"Resources": {
    "LambdaFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
            "Runtime": "python3.6",
            "Code": {
                "S3Bucket": "some-bucket",
                "S3Key": "someFile.zip"
            },
...
```

Unfortunatelly, it works only if your bucket is in the same region (e.g. us-east-2) as a Stack which you try to create with cloudFormation json/yml configuration template.

But if I want to use one configuration template for several regions? What can I do in this case? I think manual copying of the zip-file is a bit uncomfortable way.

**Is there any way to specify file from bucket of another (not current) region for Lambda source code?**

**Or perhaps somebody has already worked around the same problem?**

P.S. I have to specify source code as a file because I have some external libraries in my zip-file. Not only text script.

Comment: You'll have to figure out some other way around this problem. The Code reference here specifies the S3 bucket location that it can load the code from, and Lambda does exactly that, loads it directly into the container underlying the function. The standard way that AWS gets around using the same template in multiple regions is using `AWS::Region` in a substitution, so that there will be multiple buckets with the same prefix, and the suffix is the region. See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-security-automations/blob/master/deployment/aws-waf-security-automations.template#L837

Comment: @JamieStarke It looks like you are fully qualifying the bucket name in your template to solve the problem.  Is that correct? Would specifying the bucket fully qualified like: s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket   work?

Comment: As noted in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html: `After you create a deployment package, you may either upload it directly or upload the .zip file first to an Amazon S3 bucket in the same AWS region where you want to create the Lambda function`. In the example I linked, AWS happened to have created buckets in each region, with the region name included, so that they could direct the lambda to the bucket in the same region.